# Activity lifecycle - some strange behavior. Can't duplicate

Tags: android

That might be broad question but I will try to explain best. I will also give code snippets if anything jumps out - please let me know.

I can't repro this issue but it surface itself like so:

a. Sometime I would be logged in - I hit log out and will see my Activity refreshed. And that can happen many times. What I expect is Activity to close when I hit logout.

b. Sometime I'm on my Activity (already logged in) and started from icon. And I click back and it wouldn't go to "desktop" and goes to activity again. And this can happen 1-3 times. I expect since this is main activity to go back to desktop when hit back.

c. I noticed similar kind of issue on Yahoo mail app so I'm not sure if that is bug or 2.3.1 issue on my Nexus S?

I have:
1. Main activity
2. Login dialog that is custom dialog.

This is code from my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //If not authorized yet then show sign in dialog
        if (!PreferencesManager.getIsUserAuthenticated(getApplicationContext()))
        {
            showDialog(1);
        }

        Button signOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignOutButton);
        signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                PreferencesManager.setIsUserAuthenticated(false, getApplicationContext());
                **MainActivity.this.finish();**
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(this);

        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener()
        {
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                if (!PreferencesManager.getIsUserAuthenticated(getApplicationContext()))
                {
                    **MainActivity.this.finish();**
                }
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
```

In dialog class - I have regular stuff and "this.dismiss" if Login was successfull.

Comment: Try adding a `Log.d()` statement into `onPause`, then reproduce the error.  If you see that `onPause` was called then it may be that you were running two (or more) instances of your app, then the upper one in the stack was closed and now the lower is visible.

Comment: @dave Problem is - I can't reproduce. How do I run multiple instances?

Comment: try the different methods that Mike dg outlines.  e.g.  start from a shortcut, a widget intent, app drawer etc.

Comment: @dave Excuse me, I'm new to android :) Can you give more details? If I dragged icon on "desktop" and just click it - it's shortcut, right? If I open App list and start - it's different? What is app drawer? What is widget intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is somehow getting created multiple times. This can be do to how it's being run, if it's a shortcut from your desktop or the app drawer, or holding home, or some other shortcut.

You might want to look into launchMode at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: What is "holding home"? And does it make difference if I click "Back" vs "Home" when app open? I'm just trying to see how I can duplicate issue.

Comment: If you hold the home button on a device, it will show the most recently used apps. I forget the specifics, but I think it resends the last intent used to launch the highest activity that was previously on the stack or something. It's not really documented.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the correct way to close an Activity, but one thing you can do is to change the [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in your Manifest to singleTop to prevent the start of various instances of that Activity.

Hope it helps,
JQCorreia